# git bash nano - go to line makes text smaller

Tags: windows, git-bash, mingw-w64, nano

I try to use the function to jump to a specific line, but if I press the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> then the text size is getting smaller.

[image]

It works on another computer as intended. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Which version of MINGW64 are you using? I don't have this problem with mintty 2.9.4 on windows 10.

Comment: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> decreases text sze, you may want to check that you are actually pressing on <kbd>_</kbd> (in QWERTY UK keyboard, you need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

My fault... Of course I have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>